# Datatables dataTables.scroller.js and Fixed Columns

Tags: jquery, datatables

Did anybody use scroller extension together with fixed columns one? When trying to apply both extensions, only the header has fixed columns, while the body doesn't. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: is this you trying to achieve ? http://www.datatables.net/extensions/fixedcolumns/

Comment: Yes. But I have server-side ajax data... And I have to use Scroller extension... These two extensions dont want to work together ... (

Comment: the data anyway doesn't effect the plugin. do you want your datatable exactly as i mentioned ?

Comment: @frebinfrancis, I want to use Fixed Columns and Scroller (with server-side date) at the same time... It seems to be impossible (

Comment: no way it should be possible with the plugin.i used this plugin with the same features many times in my carrier.

Comment: @frebinfrancis could you give me some example? I mean code ... ))))

Comment: can you please show me a screenshot of your table?

Comment: @frebinfrancis of course: http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/view/?id=df0fe21
I use now just only Scroller with server-side data (Ajax)

Comment: do you want a vertical scroller or horizontal scroller on your table ? or both?

Comment: @frebinfrancis, both of course)

Comment: i think it's better to get rid of horizontal scroll bar in gridview.no one likes that.you can better use column chooser for better readability and visibility.

Comment: @frebinfrancis problem is that I have financial transactions data. Its really large volume of information. With the help of scroller extension I can show my users thousands of rows that are loading automatic. You can see on screenshot group of two blue icons in left area of table... They must be fixed on the left side... I have about fifty columns))) they are required to be shown